# Benchmarking code differs between inside and outside of foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, benchmarking

I have a section of code which looks something like this:

```
$this->benchmark->mark('start1');
$timer = 0;
foreach($x as $y)
{
    $this->benchmark->mark('start2');
    // Some code here
    $this->benchmark->mark('end2');
    $timer = $timer + $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('start2','end2');
}
var_dump('Timer = '.$timer);
$this->benchmark->mark('end1);
var_dump('Total = '.$this->benchmark->elapsed_time('start1','end1') );
```

This gives me something like

```
Timer = 0.43466
Total = 45.34421
```

How is this possible? They should be pretty much identical.

Comment: Does each iteration run so quickly it rarely registers as any elapsed time in your benchmark method?

Comment: Each iteration is about 0.001 second. There's only about 1000 iterations in total.

Comment: So which result is correct? .4 sec or 45 sec?

Comment: @DFriend .4 is what I expect to be correct... somewhere that I can't find the extra 45ish seconds is being added.

Comment: So it does take 45 sec to execute?

Comment: Yes... but I wish it didn't!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a bit like the Wave-particle duality of the photon in Quantum Mechanics. Or, it's a bug in the PHP function `microtime()`;

In trying to figure this out I first suspected that the `benchmark->elapsed_time` was the problem because it returns a string. But that wasn't involved at all.

To be sure it wasn't part of the problem I took `benchmark` out of the equation and used `microtime()` directly. The `benchmark`class mostly just uses `microtime()` anyway but I want to be sure.

Here's my first iteration

```
class Profiling extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $param = 3000000;
        $start_1 = microtime(TRUE);
        $timer = $this->long_exec_time($param);
        $end_1 = microtime(TRUE);
        echo "Timer";
        var_dump($timer);
        $total = $end_1 - $start_1;
        echo "Total";
        var_dump($total);
    }

    public function long_exec_time($param)
    {
        $timer = 0;
        for($i = 1; $i < $param; $i++)
        {
            $start_2 = microtime(TRUE);
            sqrt($i);
            $timer += (microtime(TRUE) - $start_2);
        }
        return $timer;
    }

}
```

Which outputs

> Timer
>
> float 3.8147616386414
>
> Total
>
> float 6.5267660617828

Looks like your problem. And it does actually take 6+ seconds to execute.

But if the function `long_exec_time` is defined like this

```
public function long_exec_time($param)
{
    $timer = 0;
    $start_2 = microtime(TRUE);
    for($i = 1; $i < $param; $i++)
    {
        sqrt($i);
    }
    $timer += (microtime(TRUE) - $start_2);
    return $timer;
}
```

The output is

> Timer
>
> float 2.3692939281464
>
> Total
>
> float 2.3693020343781

And yes, that is the actual execution time.

That certainly points to the repeated calls to `microtime(TRUE)` causing a longer overall execution time.

But why the two totals do not match is a mystery to me. Logically they should be a lot closer in value. The only thing that comes to mind is that `microtime` has problems of its own. I found reports of memory leaks in the function in certain environments. But I'm not sure how that would contribute to the wacky difference - if it is contributing.

All that said, I'm pretty sure if you remove the calls to `$this->benchmark->mark` inside your `foreach` loop things will go a lot faster.